# Python: elegant and code saving way to split an string in a list

Tags: python, list, optimization, coding-style

i have a string as:

```
mydata
'POINT (558750.3267372231900000 6361788.0628051758000000)'
```

i wish a code saving way to convert in a list numeric as

```
(g, (x,y))
```

where:

```
g = geometry (POINT)
x = coordinates x
y = coordinates y
```

i am using

```
mydata.split(" ")
['POINT', '(558750.3267372231900000', '6361788.0628051758000000)']
```

but after that i need to use several code line to get x and y

Comment: what about storing data in list as point objects, shapely provides method to parse your point strings for you http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely

Answer (score 3):

Step by step:

```
>>> s = 'POINT (558750.3267372231900000 6361788.0628051758000000)'
>>> word, points = s.split(None, 1)
>>> word
'POINT'
>>> points
'(558750.3267372231900000 6361788.0628051758000000)'
>>> points = points.strip('()').split()
>>> points
['558750.3267372231900000', '6361788.0628051758000000']
>>> x, y = (float(i) for i in points)
>>> x
558750.3267372232
>>> y
6361788.062805176
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex can spare you some typing here:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: def nice_tuple(s):                                                    
    g, x, y, _ = re.split(' ?[()]?', s)
    return g, tuple(map(float, (x, y)))
   ...: 

In [3]: nice_tuple('POINT (558750.3267372231900000 6361788.0628051758000000)')
Out[3]: ('POINT', (558750.3267372232, 6361788.062805176))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is always in that exact format, it's easy:

```
>>> def parse_data(d):
    geom, xs, ys = d.split()
    return (geom, (float(xs[1:]), float(ys[:-1])))

>>> mydata
'POINT (558750.3267372231900000 6361788.0628051758000000)'
>>> parse_data(mydata)
('POINT', (558750.32673722319, 6361788.0628051758))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v = mydata.split()
g = v[0]
x = float(v[1].strip('('))
y = float(v[2].strip(')'))
(g, (x, y))
```

Code saving yes, elegant not so much

Answer (score 1):

using `regex`:

```
In [59]: g,[x,y]=re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+",mydata)[0],
                       [float(x) for x in re.findall(r"[\d+.]+",mydata)]

In [60]: g
Out[60]: 'POINT'

In [61]: x
Out[61]: 558750.3267372232

In [62]: y
Out[62]: 6361788.062805176
```

using `str.strip()` and `str.split()`:

```
In [35]: mydata='POINT (558750.3267372231900000 6361788.0628051758000000)'

In [39]: data=mydata.split(None,1)

In [40]: data
Out[40]: ['POINT', '(558750.3267372231900000 6361788.0628051758000000)']

In [41]: g,[x,y]=data[0], map(lambda x: float(x.strip("()")), data[1].split())

In [42]: g,x,y
Out[42]: ('POINT', 558750.3267372232, 6361788.062805176)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
found = re.match(r'([a-zA-Z]*) \(([0-9\.]*) ([0-9\.]*)\)', mydata)
found.group(1), (float(found.group(2)), float(found.group(3)))
```

That's probably the shortest one, don't know about elegant.

Comment: You still have to convert `x` and `y` to `float`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.translate` and `.split`:

```
In [126]: mydata = 'POINT (558750.3267372231900000 6361788.0628051758000000)'

In [127]: mysplitdata = mydata.translate(None, '()').split()

In [128]: mysplitdata
Out[128]: ['POINT', '558750.3267372231900000', '6361788.0628051758000000']

In [129]: g,x,y = mysplitdata[0],float(mysplitdata[1]),float(mysplitdata[2])

In [130]: outdata = (g, (x,y))

In [131]: outdata
Out[131]: ('POINT', (558750.32673722319, 6361788.0628051758))
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I created an application in python where I did almost the same thing. Here is a class I created to parse wkt files.

[link](http://pastie.org/5489795)

Hope you find it useful. See line number 136 for usage. You can use this class to read Linestrings and Multilinestrings as well.